# GraphHopper: disable OSM ways collapsing

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

I need to match gpx file which contains track, that goes straight way, which consists of a few different OSM ways, going one after another with the same angle.

In Graphhopper answer there is a **points** field, that contains only start and end point of moving.
But I need to get all inner points of OSM ways on that straight way.

if angle in the geometry of one OSM way or angle between previous OSM way and next OSM way changes, graphhopper includes points of angle change in **points** field

Is there any url option or server config, that can enable 
getting all the inner start and end points of OSM ways, disable OSM ways collapsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code exploation shows, that there is no way to disable OSM ways collapsing without code modification